# How to run NestJs app in Docker using nx/monorepo

Tags: docker, nestjs, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have this Nrwl monorepo with a couple of apps. One of it is a NestJs app, which runs fine as long as I do everything inside my Monorepo.

However, I need to run my NestJS app inside a Docker container. I noticed that I cannot simply copy the compiled NestJS code into an Image, because it still requires `node_modules`.

The only easy solution I can think of is to also copy the main `package.json` file into the image and run `npm install`. Is this the correct/only way or does Nrwl/nx has tooling for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set generatePackageJson to true in workspace.json. Nx will generate a package.json in the dist folder for you.

/apps/<your.app>/project.json

```
{
  "name": "your.app",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "generatePackageJson": true 
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Although your solution works, I cannot run `npm ci`, it complains that `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are not in sync

Comment: I don't have an issue with that. you can try to delete all cached files (node_modules, dists, .next, etc..). after that run `npm install` in the root project to create a new package-lock.json file. and then run your build command for your backend. this should work

Comment: also what about extra dependencies from other projects?

Comment: @ciekawy Can you describe it in more detail?

Comment: Sure - having frontend and backend app and only single root level package.json building docker image makes some 1.5GB image in my case. I added poor man regexp to remove in place FE does to go down to 400MB but I’d expect it to be reasonably handled by nx. Actually I’d expect still package.json by app while keeping them in single root level node_modules - probably this is one of the reasonable option coming to my mind…

Comment: I build the frontend and the backend with nx. In addition, the package.json is also created for me by nx.

My docker image is then organized as follows:
- COPY binaries
- COPY package.json
- RUN npm i
- CMD node main.js

I don't know any other way. I have the disadvantage that some node_modules are installed twice. But that doesn't bother me. Alternatively, you can copy all node_modules to your docker image and then delete the unused node_modules. This may be faster. To delete unused node_modules with `npm prune`

Answer (score 2):

As `workspace.json` [is now deprecated](https://nx.dev/deprecated/workspace-json), `generatePackageJson` option moved to [@nx/webpack:webpack package](https://nx.dev/packages/webpack/executors/webpack#generatepackagejson) so a modern (as of 2023) way to make it work is to either:

1. Define a default in `nx.json`:

```json
{
  "targetDefaults": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/webpack:webpack",
      "options": {
        "generatePackageJson": true
      },
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

2. Define a project-specific setting in `project.json`:

```json
{
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/webpack:webpack",
      "options": {
        "generatePackageJson": true
      },
      //...
    },
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

3. Define a project-specific setting in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "scripts": {
    // ...
  },
  "nx": {
    "targets": {
      "build": {
        "executor": "@nx/webpack:webpack",
        "options": {
          "generatePackageJson": true
        },
      },
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```